# running PHP, Mysql project locally using xamp

Tags: php, mysql, ftp, xampp, filezilla

So I am trying to work on admin page of a small website.

Here is what I need help with:
Project has been built on PHP and MySQL. I grabbed the source code from hosting using Filezilla.

Installed xampp and everything is running fine. Tried some php code and it seems alright.

Now my question is, If I want to run the whole project locally do I need to create local MySQL database too? Can I connect to existing database from hosting?
For now when I run **index.php** file of project nothing really happens, which I guess is okay since I am not connected to database right?

If somebody could walk me through the process of getting it running locally, that would be great!

Comment: Yep. It's better to create a local MySQL database because most of the remote DBs will not allow connections from outside.

Comment: Maybe you could, but would you want to mess up your live database everytime you make a little coding/SQL error. We all make coding errors, but on a test database its not a problem

Comment: Turns out some hostings has actually online editor I can use for small changes

Answer (score -1):

If your hosting allows external MySQL connections, you should have no problem connecting directly to the hosting MySQL databases. Just specify the correct IP for host and the correct port.

Comment: See my comment for one, of many, reasons this is not a sensible idea